# Symfony2 Authentication "login_check" path not found (what does it mean by put /login_check behind the firewall)

Tags: symfony, authentication, acl

I am struggling with this from quite a some time, getting the error "Symfony2 Authentication "login_check" path not found Controller" , in the documentation of common pitfalls they have mentioned that you should put /login_check behind the firewall, but not able to figure it out how to deal with it.

Comment: Post your firewall configuration of security.yml

Comment: Thanks but do i need to create it under firewall section in security.yml if i do it like that it throws not found registered listener for the same.

Comment: firewalls
        main:
            remember_me:
                key: %secret%
                lifetime: 1209600
                path: /
                domain: ~
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                use_forward:    false
                login_path: /login
                success_handler: login_success_handler
                failure_path:   null
                use_referer:    true
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /about
            anonymous: ~

Comment: Update your question with the security.yml stuff.  Indent it 4 spaces so it's readable.

Comment: firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            remember_me:
                key: %secret%
                lifetime: 1209600
                path: /
                domain: ~
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                use_forward:    false
                login_path: /login
                success_handler: login_success_handler
                failure_path:   null
                use_referer:    true
            anonymous: ~

Comment: Not the comments.  Used the Edit link and the stuff directly to your question.